# Type backward referring in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-generics

I need help with type declaration that contains a backward referring and I'll explain:

Given an interface `Car` like that:

```js
interface Car {
  name: string,
  engine: Engine,
  brand: Brand,
  ...
}
```

I need to create a type of the following structure:

```js
[ 'engine', (engine1, engine2) => {...} ]
```

Where `engine1` and `engine2` will be the same type as `Car['engine']` and without limitation of generality - I need an array of:

```js
[(keyof T) as S, (s1: S, s2: S) => { ... }]
```

In words: an array that contains exactly two elements: the first - is a property of T and the second is a function that accepts `arg1` and `arg2` where their type is **the same type as the type of `T[the first item in the array]`**

Can someone help me to declare such a type?

Answer (score 2):

This will do:

```
type MyType<T extends object> = { [S in keyof T]: [S, (s1: T[S], s2: T[S]) => any] }[keyof T];

const e: MyType<Car> = ['engine', (e1: Engine, e2: Engine) => { }];
```

Explanation (due to request in comment):

Just break it apart.
Consider type:

```
type MyType1<T extends object, S extends keyof T> = [S, (s1: T[S], s2: T[S]) => any];
```

This type seems pretty obvious. But has one disadvantage - you must type key name explicitly.

```
const e: MyType1<Car, 'engine'> = ['engine', (e1: Engine, e2: Engine) => { }];
```

So you make union of all MyType1 possibilities for each property key:

```
type MyType2<T extends object> = { [S in keyof T]: MyType1<T, S> }[keyof T];
```

The original type above was just these two steps in one ;).

Comment: Elegant :) A bit explanation would help to future readers.

Comment: Looks good. Unfortunately, I can't upvote twice ;)

Answer (score 0):

There is maybe a better approach but this is what I have.

I can't see a way to do it with a "plain" type so my suggestion is to create a "factory" - basically a function to create this kind of array.

This gives more flexibility with creating types.

```ts
type Engine = {
  model: number;
}
type Brand = {
  name: string;
}

interface Car {
  name: string;
  engine: Engine;
  brand: Brand;
}

interface ArrayFactory<T> {
  <U extends keyof T>(prop: U): [U, (arg1: T[U], arg2: T[U]) => void];
}

const createArray: ArrayFactory<Car> = (prop) => [prop, (arg1, arg2) => console.log(arg1, arg2)];

const arr = createArray('engine');
console.log(arr[0] === 'engine1');
arr[1]({model: 1}, {model: 2})
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=22&pc=31#code/C4TwDgpgBAogdgcwJZ2gXigbwFBSgWwHsATCAGwC4o4BXfAIwgCcBubAX21EigCEmAhnGJQMOPHAH4IVAM7AmKBG07YUwZgDMBAY2gBhAUyy5qUmVHmLEbPBEQoL8ZKltR6g4VX5DiK7GpwGkzaelAAgkyCIABiusCETCAAPAAqAHwmeMkAqlAQAB4awrJQANYQIISaUBkAFGBMhGBUOQCUVADaOQA0UHVGCACMVKndALp9gwBMoxNtopkAboRIxOP+2DqEcPJQOkwQAhqR0VSnArHxiSmGTJkYDU1gC2iZnY3NfQNMw1O-01emW2u0IZAgADoyIQED8-lAZm0NgEQXsjMYMAcjicopc6gByewuCD4tpsVFgyHQ2HozoABnGojQGEJDlQQ1JbFpQ3GdUwRFIlCgQ3YfX5JHIVGm7DaQA)